# Treeview from Self Lookup List

Tags: web-part, list-view, custom-list, 2016, sharepoint-list

I have been assigned a project to develop a SharePoint site that will help us track a set of objects. These objects can have dependent objects (or not). I have used a Lookup column and created a self-reference.

Once of the aspects of the project is that I need to be able to pass in a parameter (object name) and return a tree view of all of the dependent objects. There could be n levels of dependency.

I'm not sure how to query in the SharePoint list to return n levels of dependent objects. I feel like I would use a CAML Query, but I don't know how to get it to output to include an unknown number of levels of dependency.

Forgot to mention that we are running 2016 standard on-premise. (an enterprise is an option if it is needed)

Here is how the list is structured:

```
ObjName (Single Line) - ImportantInformation (MultiLine) - DependentObj (Lookup to ObjName)
Obj1                    Something Important                
Obj2                    Other Important BS                 Obj1
Obj3                    NotImportant                       Obj2, Obj1
Obj4                    aklsdjfklj                         
Obj5                    aksdjfkjasdk                       Obj4
```

Expected output with input of Obj3: (example in JSON format, but not required)

```
[  
   {  
      "ObjName":"Obj3",
      "DependantObjs":[  
         {  
            "ObjName":"Obj1"
         },
         {  
            "ObjName":"Obj2",
            "DependantObjs":[  
               {  
                  "ObjName":"Obj1"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Maybe output in -UL--LI- format?

My question is: What options/techniques are available to do this? Custom Web part with CAML? Custom stored procedure in SharePoint SQL servers? Modified List View with JSLink?

Comment: Nobody has any ideas on where I would even get started for this?